# Connect to memcached using PHP on Windows

Tags: php, iis, amazon-web-services, memcached

I have a memcached server (on AWS ElastiCache) and need to connect to it using PHP on Windows (IIS not WAMP).

Is this possible?

I have found `php_memcache.dll` but this doesn't appear to work with memcached. I guess I need `php_memcached.dll`?

Does this exist and where can I find it?

Comment: 1) When you ay "it doesn't appear to work", do you mean it just doesn't appear in `phpinfo()` or that it does but you can't connect to your memcached server? 2) what version of PHP are you using? 3) are you running the recommended non-threadsafe build with fastcgi? 4) What version of Windows/IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main [memcached](http://memcached.org/) clients for PHP, [memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) and [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached). You can see a comparison of the two versions [here](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PHPClientComparison). The biggest difference is probably the memcached extension's reliance on [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html). This gives the memcached client a number of additional capabilities. In my searching though, I have been unable to find a working dll for the memcached client library. This means that the memcache library is basically your only choice on Windows unless you want to try and compile it yourself (based on the lack of an available dll this is probably very difficult) or use a pure-PHP library like [xslib-memcached](https://github.com/pompo500/xslib-memcached), but you're likely to find much more support for the memcache client.

I have not attempted to use the memcache client on IIS, but I have used it with Apache on Windows 7 (32-bit builds on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows) connecting to a local memcached server, so I know that there are working builds of this client.

If your running on AWS, you should really consider using Linux. It's much cheaper than running Windows instances and will probably run PHP better than IIS on Windows.